# Changing image properties in Java Help using CSS doesn't work

Tags: java, html, css

I'm currently working on a help system for my Java project (a desktop application) and I'm using Java Help. The only problem I'm having is that I can't change img properties in css. It doesn't work in the application, but it does work in a web brower. I want to make the images resizes as the help window does, like the text, but this is what I get:

[image: Screenshot]

This is what I have in my css to resize the images:

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
}
```

And this is the html of the screenshot:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Introduction</title>
        <link rel=StyleSheet type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Introduction</h1>
        <p>This text is getting resized as the help system windows does,
           but the image below doesn't:</p>
        <p></p>
        <img src="img/java.jpg">
    </body>
</html>
```

Trying to change any other img properties seems useless as well, as they are never displayed in the application (but they always work in a web browser).

EDIT: Here's the code for the Java Help system creation (this method is called as the main window is initialized and when the language is changed):

```
private void loadHelp() {
    HelpSet hs;
    try {
        URL url = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("help/" + manager.getText("help_set"));
        hs = new HelpSet(null, url);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, manager.getText("error_help"), manager.getText("error_title"),
                JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        return;
    }
    HelpBroker hb = hs.createHelpBroker();
    hb.enableHelpKey(frame.getContentPane(), manager.getText("help_introduction"), hs);
    hb.enableHelpOnButton(getMntmManual(), manager.getText("help_introduction"), hs);
}
```

Comment: what about putting `100%` on `width` and `height` ?

Comment: @ElmaCherb It doesn't work

Comment: does it work when you change properties of `h1` or `body` elements ? this problem is general to all elements or just `img` element ?

Comment: This only seems to affect img elements

Comment: can you try to add `object-fit: cover;` to img css

Comment: It doesn't work either. I guess It's something related with Java Help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195765/discussion-between-elma-cherb-and-novayhulk14).

Comment: JavaHelp uses Swing to display content, and Swing’s HTML renderer only supports HTML 3.2 and CSS 1.x.  While this is limiting and can be frustrating, it is worth noting that user help should just be documentation and shouldn’t need to be complex.